# Return one row from stored procedure in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I one to create a stored procedure to retrieve one row in the table:

```
create procedure LogInUser
    @username nvarchar(64),
    @password nvarchar(64),
    @succeed bit out,   
    @not_exist_err bit out
as
declare @exist_user nvarchar(64)
select @exist_user = username from users
where username = @username

if @exist_user is null
begin
    set @succeed = 0
    set @not_exist_err = 1
    return
end
else
begin
    select * from users
    where username = @username and password = @password 
end
return
```

First, I verify if a user exist or not by using:

```
select @exist_user = username from users
where username = @username
```

Then get the row with every column:

```
select * from users
where username = @username and password = @password
```

However, by using `SqlDataReader`, the program won't enter the while loop to retrieve the information.

It just don't enter the loop. I don't understand why, even I executed it using SQL Server like this, it did return a row:

```
declare @succeedResult bit
declare @existErr bit
exec LogInUser @username=admin, @password =admin, @succeed = @succeedResult, @not_exist_err = @existErr
```

**EDIT**: The C# method which executes the store procedure:

```
public User LogIn(User usr)
{
   SqlConnection conn = A2.Controller.Utils.conn;
   SqlCommand loginCmd = new SqlCommand("LogInUser", conn);
   loginCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   User result = new User();

   try
   {
       conn.Open();
       loginCmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = usr.Username;
       loginCmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = usr.Password;
       loginCmd.Parameters.Add("@succeed", SqlDbType.Bit).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
       loginCmd.Parameters.Add("@not_exist_err", SqlDbType.Bit).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;                
       SqlDataReader dr = loginCmd.ExecuteReader();              

       if (loginCmd.Parameters["@succeed"].Value != DBNull.Value){
          Console.WriteLine("User does not exist");
          SqlParameter notExistErr = loginCmd.Parameters["@not_exist_err"];

          if (notExistErr.Value != DBNull.Value){
             throw new NotExistException("The username or password is incorrect.", "Users");
          }
       }

       while (dr.Read()) {
           Console.WriteLine("Looping dr");
           result.Username = (string) dr["username"];
           result.Password = (string) dr["password"];
           result.FirstName = (string) dr["first_name"];
           result.MiddleName = (string) dr["middle_name"];
           result.LastName = (string) dr["last_name"];
           result.ManagerID = (int) dr["manager_id"];
           result.IsAdmin = (int) dr["is_admin"];

           return result;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done reading");
    }             
    finally {
       if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: Could you add the part of the C# code where you execute the stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output parameters are only filled after you read the last row from the last result set in the procedure.  So this part won't work:

```
SqlDataReader dr = loginCmd.ExecuteReader();              
if (loginCmd.Parameters["@succeed"].Value != DBNull.Value){
```

At this point `loginCmd.Parameters["@succeed"].Value` is not set: it will be set only after you've read the last row, and `dr.Read()` has returned `false`.

As a best practice, don't use `output` parameters in stored procedures that return rowsets.

Comment: wow it works. Thanks a lot. I wish I could find a something like this on MSDN -_-

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether your query returns the result or is not using `dr.HasRows`, and it should look like...

```
SqlDataReader dr = loginCmd.ExecuteReader();              
if (!dr.HasRows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("User does not exist");
    SqlParameter notExistErr = loginCmd.Parameters["@not_exist_err"];
    if (notExistErr.Value != DBNull.Value)
    {
        throw new NotExistException("The username or password is incorrect.", "Users");
    }
}
else
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Looping dr");
        result.Username = (string) dr["@username"];
        result.Password = (string) dr["@password"];
        result.FirstName = (string) dr["@first_name"];
        result.MiddleName = (string) dr["@middle_name"];
        result.LastName = (string) dr["@last_name"];
        result.ManagerID = (int) dr["@manager_id"];
        result.IsAdmin = (int) dr["@is_admin"];
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is strange -- I would expect your test to look like this:

```
declare @succeedResult bit
declare @existErr bit
exec LogInUser @username=N'admin', @password =N'admin', @succeed = @succeedResult, @not_exist_err = @existErr
```

But this brings up the simple answer.... are you calling your function with valid (ie exist) for username AND password?

Comment: Yes, I did it with valid username and password, and VS did return a row. I execute it in visual studio (Not SQL Server though).